# MIT App Inventor and Arduino Ethernet LED Error 1109 URL not valid

Tags: android, arduino, ethernet

I am beginning the basis for a home automation system using an arduino with ethernet and a phone with software that I programmed with MIT App inventor. I've been playing with code from a tutorial and got my LED to turn on and off fine from a local computer using the internet by using a browser and navigating the url 192.168.1.10/$1

```
/*  thrown together by Randy Sarafan

 Allows you to turn on and off an LED by entering different urls.

 To turn it on:
 http://192.168.1.10/$1

 To turn it off:
 http://192.168.1.10/$2

     Based almost entirely upon Web Server by Tom Igoe and David Mellis

     Edit history: 
     created 18 Dec 2009
     by David A. Mellis
     modified 4 Sep 2010
     by Tom Igoe

     */

    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <Ethernet.h>

    boolean incoming = 0;

    // Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
    // The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
    byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDA, 0x02 };
    //IPAddress ip(191,168,1,15); //<<< ENTER YOUR IP ADDRESS HERE!!! i commented this out and did it on the router side

    // Initialize the Ethernet server library
    // with the IP address and port you want to use 
    // (port 80 is default for HTTP):
    EthernetServer server(80);

    void setup()
    {
      pinMode(8, OUTPUT);

      // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
      Ethernet.begin(mac);
      server.begin();
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop()
    {
      // listen for incoming clients
      EthernetClient client = server.available();
      if (client) {
        // an http request ends with a blank line
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
        while (client.connected()) {
          if (client.available()) {
            char c = client.read();
            // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
            // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
            // so you can send a reply

            //reads URL string from $ to first blank space
            if(incoming && c == ' '){ 
              incoming = 0;
            }
            if(c == '$'){ 
              incoming = 1; 
            }

            //Checks for the URL string $1 or $2
            if(incoming == 1){
              Serial.println(c);

              if(c == '1'){
                Serial.println("ON");
                digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
              }
              if(c == '2'){
                Serial.println("OFF");
                digitalWrite(8, LOW);
              }

            }

            if (c == '\n') {
              // you're starting a new line
              currentLineIsBlank = true;
            } 
            else if (c != '\r') {
              // you've gotten a character on the current line
              currentLineIsBlank = false;
            }
          }
        }
        // give the web browser time to receive the data
        delay(1);
        // close the connection:
        client.stop();
      }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is on the mobile side. I created an app with MIT app inventor that should toggle the IP, but instead gives me:

> error 1109: The specified URL is not valid: 192.168.1.10/$1

Im quite perplexed. I know that this URL IS VALID because I've connected to it before. Is there a way to override this or otherwise fix it?

Here's the MIT app inventor AIA source: http://www.filedropper.com/internetled

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD specify the IP address in the code itself. And change "Ethernet.begin(mac);" to "Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);".

You should also try to open the web page in the browser to check if it works, before trying it out with App Inventor.

Answer (score -1):

In AppInventor error "error 1109: The specified URL is not valid: 192.168.1.10/$1" you may have forgotten to put the "http: //" in your address.
Example, if you are saving the address in a global variable or tinyDB, you should put http://192.168.1.10/$1
This would be your address to connect the led.

Comment: What's the reason for portuguese version?

Comment: I wrote in google translator and I copied the translation, but I did not see that I had copied the Portuguese either, I did an English edition only, sorry for this